# Linux Raid5 faulty array

Tags: linux, raid

Facts first:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sd[abcd]3 |egrep 'dev|Update|Role|State|Chunk Size'

/dev/sda3:
    Update Time : Thu Jul 19 22:42:40 2012
          State : active
     Chunk Size : 64K
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   0     0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   3     3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
/dev/sdb3:
    Update Time : Thu Jul 19 22:42:07 2012
          State : active
     Chunk Size : 64K
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   0     0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   1     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   3     3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
/dev/sdc3:
    Update Time : Mon Sep 12 18:12:24 2011
          State : active
     Chunk Size : 64K
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
   0     0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   1     1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
   2     2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
   3     3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
/dev/sdd3:
    Update Time : Thu Jul 19 22:42:40 2012
          State : active
     Chunk Size : 64K
      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
   0     0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
   3     3       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
------------------------------------------------------------------
Smartctl says for disk b,c,d PASSED
Disk A is:

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.11
Device Model:     ST31500341AS
Serial Number:    9VS38YXA
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 01a5e61f6
Firmware Version: CC1H
User Capacity:    1,500,301,910,016 bytes [1.50 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Fri Jul 20 16:24:39 2012 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.
```

Has someone an idea how to possibly rebuild the raid. The problem is that our backup system
has 2 failed drives (all within 24h) and it would take days to rebuild the system and to reupload all data, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should ask this question on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com), it's offtopic here.  Anyways, good luck.

Comment: What are the relevant lines of your /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something but this seems like a pretty straight forward replacement of a disk.

- Remove the /dev/sda3 from the array,
- locate the disk with the serial # of 9VS38YXA and remove it from the machine
- Replace the disk with a new one
- Add the new disk to the array

The array should then start to rebuild